# Cold brewed coffee

Tags: adjuncts, coffee

I have a recipe that calls for adding a gallon of cold brewed coffee in the secondary. The comments have described how to cold brew it, but I was wondering, do I need to add the grounds plus the gallon, or just the spent grounds? I don't want to dilute the beer with an extra gallon, but would still like to get the flavor of the coffee.

Comment: dude, can you share the recipe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not add the grounds.  Add the liquid.  And a gal. sounds like WAY too much.  When I make a coffee beer, generally a cup or two of strong coffee is plenty.

Comment: FWIW I already did. Decided to add 6 ounces of dry grounds. It's a strong dark beer already, so it shouldn't be overpowering. I'll add a link to the recipe in a bit

Comment: As long as you didn't add them to the boil, you may be OK.  When I use coffee, I usually "dry bean" by adding 4-5 oz. of coarsely cracked beans to the secondary.

Comment: Yes, it was in the secondary. I should have mentioned that in the question. Edited appropriately.